# In tensorflow, how can I index a feature's value given another feature as a key?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-transform

I have a feature preprocessing problem that is just a bit too complex for me to solve.
I want to generate a “cross-feature” out of 3 others, let me detail:

My ML problem is to recommend item to users.
In my example there are features about the users and features about the item. I’m trying to predict if the user will like this item or not.
We use tensorflow examples.

On of my user’s features is a “map” of item ids to the user’s “affinity” for them. Let’s call it “map of item affinities”
The affinity itself is computed by another process.
Since there is no map type in Tensorflow Examples, we have 2 features: one is the ordered list of item ids, the other is the ordered list of affinities. They are synchronous. So my “map of item affinities” is actually represented by to features `item_affinities_ids` and `item affinities`.
Yes, I’m using items affinity information as an input and try to predict another item affinity. But those are different, the input is computed for a different product use-case than the one I am trying to predict.

I also have a 3rd feature which is the the `item_id` of the item I’m trying to compute a new affinity for.

In naive numpy I could do it like this:

```py
item_name = np.array(["item-a"])
item_affinities_ids = np.array(["item-0", "item-a", "item-b"])
item_affinities = np.array([0.2, 0.3, 0.4])
indices = np.where(item_affinities_ids == item_name)
return item_affinities[indices]
```

Now, where things can get more complicated is in real life:

- I want a tensorflow implementation (TFT or native TF).
- We use TF v.13
- The “map of item affinities”  can be missing. So the two resulting `item_affinities_ids` and `item affinities` are represented as `SparseTensor`s. However if one is there, the other too, and they are guaranteed to be synchronous (same size, same order).
- We do prediction and training on batches of examples, so the first dimension of each of my (Sparse)Tensors is the batch_size > 1.
- The `item_id` may not exists in the “map of item affinities”. In that case I want a default value (0.0).

I’m looking for a tensorflow implementation that would deal with all of these requirements.
So far I have:

```py
# using constants for the demonstration. In real life it would be tensors.
item_name = tf.constant([["item-a"], ["item-3"]])
item_affinities_ids = tf.constant([["item-0", "item-a", "item-b"], ["item-2", "item-1", "item-3"]])
item_affinities = tf.constant([[0.2, 0.3, 0.4], [0.2, -0.9, 0.4]])
return tf.boolean_mask(item_affinities, tf.equal(item_affinities_ids, item_name))
```

But it does not handle SparseTensor and the case when the item_id is not in the `item_affinities` list.
I’m looking for anyone to help me with that.

Comment: There's `tf.where`, tensorflow deliberately mirrors numpy to a significant extent. I suspect you can use nearly identical code with `np` replaced with `tf`.

Comment: Martin Laurent, can you try David Parks's suggestion and confirm if it works. If it is not working, you can mention where you are stuck so that we can try from there.

Comment: I managed to write a solution using this, but I could not avoid to densify my SparseTensor because tf.where does not exists for SparseTensors. I am looking specifically for a solution without densifying the input tensors.